Milvus - Kafka partitioning strategy
We are using kafka as a message stream with Milvus. when we logged into broker and watch the log directory. we always observing that only 1 partition is being used by log files though we have overriden broker config (num.partitions = 2) to create 2 partitions. Milvus writing data to only 1 partition the other partition log file is always 0 bytes. In below snapshot only partition 0 is considered by Milvus.
Which partition strategy is being used by Milvus and how to obtain Producer and consumer configs? Do we gain any advantage if we increase number of partition in kafka if ingestion rate is too high, the default is 1?
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 1001     0 Sep 12 01:21 by-dev-rootcoord-dml_8-1/00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 1001  622K Sep 12 01:31 by-dev-rootcoord-dml_8-0/00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 1001  947K Sep 12 01:31 by-dev-rootcoord-dml_8-0/00000000000000001963.log



So far as I know, milvus doesn't specify any partition when creating consumer of kafka. I suppose it always uses the default/first partition.
